# Subset a Variadic template given a constexpr boolean selection function

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose we have a variadic templated class like

```
template<class...Ts>
class X{
template<size_t I>
constexpr bool shouldSelect();

std::tuple<TransformedTs...> mResults; // this is want I want eventually
};
```

where the implementation of `shouldSelect` is not provided, but what it does is that, given an index `i` referring to the `i`th element of the variadic `Ts`, tells you whether we should select it to the subset.

I want to do a transformation on `Ts` such that only classes `T`s at indexes that results in `shouldSelect` returning true should be selected. Is there an easy way to do this?

For example, if shouldSelect returns true for I = 1,2,4, and Ts... = short, int, double, T1, T2, then I want to get a `TransformedTs...` that is made up of `int, double, T2`. Then I can use this `TransformedTs...` in the same class.

Comment: Is the `shouldSelect` method something required? Probably easier to deal with that logic in the type trait instead of having to involve and outside function and dealing with indexes of a variadic pack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're able to use C++17, this is pretty easy to implement using a combination of `if constexpr` and expression folding.

Start with some helper types, one with parameters to track the arguments to `X::shouldSelect<I>()`, and the other with a type to test.

```cpp
template <typename T, size_t I, typename...Ts>
struct Accumulator {
    using Type = std::tuple<Ts...>;
};

template <typename T>
struct Next { };
```

Then an operator overload either adds the type to the accumulator, or not with `if constexpr`:

```cpp
template <typename TAcc, size_t I, typename... Ts, typename TArg>
decltype(auto) operator +(Accumulator<TAcc, I, Ts...>, Next<TArg>) {
    if constexpr (TAcc::template shouldSelect<I>()) {
        return Accumulator<TAcc, I + 1, Ts..., TArg>{};
    } else {
        return Accumulator<TAcc, I + 1, Ts...>{};
    }
}
```

Finally, you can put it all together with a fold expression and extract the type with `decltype`:

```cpp
template <template <typename... Ts> class T, typename... Ts>
constexpr decltype(auto) FilterImpl(const T<Ts...>&) {
    return (Accumulator<T<Ts...>, 0>{} + ... + Next<Ts>{});
}

template<typename T>
using FilterT = typename decltype(FilterImpl(std::declval<T>()))::Type;
```

Usage:

```cpp
using Result = FilterT<X<int, double, bool, etc>>;
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/9h89zG

---

If you don't have C++17 available to you, it's still possible. You can do the same sort of conditional type transfer using a recursive inheritance chain to iterate though each type in the parameter pack, and `std::enable_if` to do the conditional copy. Below is the same code, but working in C++11:

```cpp
// Dummy type for copying parameter packs
template <typename... Ts>
struct Mule {};

/* Filter implementation */
template <typename T, typename Input, typename Output, size_t I, typename = void>
struct FilterImpl;

template <typename T, typename THead, typename... TTail, typename... OutputTs, size_t I>
struct FilterImpl<T, Mule<THead, TTail...>, Mule<OutputTs...>, I, typename std::enable_if<( T::template shouldSelect<I>() )>::type >
    : FilterImpl<T, Mule<TTail...>, Mule<OutputTs..., THead>, (I + 1)>
{ };

template <typename T, typename THead, typename... TTail, typename... OutputTs, size_t I>
struct FilterImpl<T, Mule<THead, TTail...>, Mule<OutputTs...>, I, typename std::enable_if<( !T::template shouldSelect<I>() )>::type >
    : FilterImpl<T, Mule<TTail...>, Mule<OutputTs...>, (I + 1)>
{ };

template <typename T, typename... OutputTs, size_t I>
struct FilterImpl<T, Mule<>, Mule<OutputTs...>, I>
{ 
    using Type = std::tuple<OutputTs...>;
};

/* Helper types */
template <typename T>
struct Filter;

template <template <typename... Ts> class T, typename... Ts>
struct Filter<T<Ts...>> : FilterImpl<T<Ts...>, Mule<Ts...>, Mule<>, 0>
{ };

template <typename T>
using FilterT = typename Filter<T>::Type;
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/esso4M